# Converting an oracle query to JPQL Query......!

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jpa, jpql

I have an oralce query like this

```
select * from CBH.MCBH_BABY_INFO mbc 
 where 
 MBC.MARKETINGCBHID in (625588,4238636,5220648) 
 and (MBC.WERKELIJKE_GEBOORTEDATUM is null or  MBC.WERKELIJKE_GEBOORTEDATUM >(sysdate-30));
```

and i converted this query to JPQL query like this

```
QUERY_SEL_BY_MCBH_ID_LIST = "SELECT mc FROM MarketingCbhBabyInfo mc "+
                                                           "WHERE mc.marketingCbh.id in :mcbhIdList"+
                                                            "AND (mc.WERKELIJKE_GEBOORTEDATUM IS NULL "+
                                                            "OR mc.WERKELIJKE_GEBOORTEDATUM >(CURRENT_DATE-:days))";
```

and in the DAO class I am passing idlist and days like this.

```
List<MarketingCbhBabyInfo> marketingCbhBabyInfoList = this.em.createNamedQuery(MarketingCbhBabyInfo.SEL_BY_MCBH_ID_LIST,MarketingCbhBabyInfo.class)
                                                             .setParameter("mcbhIdList",mcbhIdList)
                                                             .setParameter("days",days)
                                                             .getResultList();


I have converted the above query to jpql query but it is giving me

 Filter invalid. Cannot compare field realBirthDate of type java.util.Date to value of type java.lang.Number. Numeric comparisons must be between numeric types only. To enable such comparisons for backwards-compatibility, add "QuotedNumbersInQueries=true" to the org.apache.openjpa.Compatibility setting in your configuration.
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.exps.AbstractExpressionBuilder.convertTypes(AbstractExpressionBuilder.java:435)
```

Comment: why don't you just try it?!

Comment: i do have some configuration issues

Comment: Well when you've sorted those issues out you can try it